# Your device isn't compatible with this version..Play store error

Tags: android, google-play

I uploaded an Android app in Play store and It was published. Now I'm unable to download.
It displays "Your device isn't compatible with this version"...

My compileSdkVersion 26
BuildToolsVerdion 26.0.2
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 23

Is this issue happens due to version 26 or something else?

Thanks

Comment: Did You uninstalled Your debug version from Your device? If not - do it, perhaps that is the issue.

Comment: I uninstalled it then opened play store. IT is the same for all devices.

Comment: Go to Play store console -> release management -> device catalog. See the supported devices list. Can You find the devices You are using there?

Comment: Yes Pavel. And it says This device model is not supported in your app's APK manifest and hence users of this device model cannot install your app.

Comment: These case happens, when we use such a library or service which supports deprecated methods, For removing such error, We need to replace that library or services.

Answer (score 6):

I was using **uses-feature** in Manifest file for **Camera2** with **required=true**. 
This made all devices unsupported.
Now that I changed to **required=false** and everything is fine as expected.

Comment: There's no uses-feature flag for camera2 defined in the Android SDK; the camera2 API is always available since Android L. So if you add that kind of uses-feature flag, no device will be listed as supporting it.

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be marked as it. Thanks Selvam.

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for receiving the above error message while trying to download applications from the Google Play Store is that your current Android device may be running on an older version of Android.

Comment: My current version is 7.0 Nougat and this issue is existing in all devices irrespective of platform.

Answer (score 0):

Update your firmware accordingly, the possible reason could be the compatibility issue.
Your app must be developed using APIs which are now not compatible with current version of your firmware. If it is updated to latest, try using it on other device.

Answer (score 0):

> If you are using `<supports-screens>` tag in manifest, remove that tag, this helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved.
go to your build.gradle(app) and comment buildToolsVersion. my compilesdkversion and targetsdk are 31. (though 32 is also available but no stable yet). publish your app. you're done.